# How to pass a string buffer from python function to C Api via ctype

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a C api function with the following prototype which I wish to call from Python 2.6/2.7 via the ctypes module.

C function :

```
int function_name( char *outputbuffer, int outputBufferSize, 
                   const char *input, const char *somestring2 );
```

Here outputbuffer is a kind of string buffer in which a string is to be inserted as the output once this function is called on the basis of input and somestring2.

How do we create this buffer (output buffer) in python and what would be the argtype for this function

Comment: I'm not an expert in Python, but check `ctypes` and `create_string_buffer`.

Comment: Why did you add the c++ tag? The question clearly indicates that the topic of interest is a "C api function".

Comment: @pqans sorry for any kind of  inconvenience caused . I guess the c++ tag was there in recommendations, so got added inadvertently. will delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you import the ctypes module. Then you need to load your c dll containing the said function. After that you need to set the argument types and the result type of that function. Finally you create your destination buffer and call your function.

Python:

```
import ctypes as ct

MAX_BUFSIZE = 100
  
mycdll = ct.CDLL("path_to_your_c_dll")  # for windows you use ct.WinDLL(path)

mycdll.function_name.argtypes = [ct.c_char_p, ct.c_int,
                                 ct.c_char_p, ct.c_char_p]

mycdll.function_name.restype = ct.c_int

mystrbuf = ct.create_string_buffer(MAX_BUFSIZE)
result = mycdll.function_name(mystrbuf, len(mystrbuf), 
                              b"my_input", b"my_second_input")
```

Working example using strncpy:

```
import ctypes as ct

MAX_BUFSIZE = 100

mycdll = ct.CDLL("libc.so.6")  # on windows you use cdll.msvcrt, instead

mycdll.strncpy.argtypes = [ct.c_char_p, ct.c_char_p, ct.c_size_t]

mycdll.strncpy.restype = ct.c_char_p

mystrbuf = ct.create_string_buffer(MAX_BUFSIZE)
dest = mycdll.strncpy(mystrbuf, b"my_input", len(mystrbuf))

print(mystrbuf.value)
```

Python 3 output:

```
user@Mint20:~/Dokumente/Programmieren/sites/Stackoverflow$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5

user@Mint20:~/Dokumente/Programmieren/sites/Stackoverflow$ python3 python_ctypes.py 
b'my_input'
```

Python 2 output:

```
user@Mint20:~/Dokumente/Programmieren/sites/Stackoverflow$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.18

user@Mint20:~/Dokumente/Programmieren/sites/Stackoverflow$ python2 python_ctypes.py 
my_input
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i am not getting the output stored/returned in the mystrbuf . Also, i tried sending the inputs both ways like you suggested as b"my_input" , and ct.c_char_p("my_input"). But mystrbuf is still empty. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Instead of loading your c code, load the `libc.so.6` or the `msvcrt` if you are working on linux or windows respectively.  Replace the _function_name_ with _strncpy_ and provide the correct arg- and restypes. Then you see that it works! How is your c code looking?

Comment: I just added an working example with the suggested strncpy

Comment: one more thing forgot to add , i am working on python 2. Is there any major change in ctypes for python 2 and 3 ?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html, however i don't know the featureset of this early version.

Comment: Huh, i just ran it with Python 2.7.18 and it worked out of the box with the strncpy testcase. There must be some issue with your c code. If you post it here, maybe we can help.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It is working. Earlier, I had parked this issue aside and picked this up today.